# Difference between ASR and LSR

Tags: linux, arm

What is the difference for shift right? I know ASL and LSL are the same but I don't know difference for ASR and LSR, I have tried searching but could not find a solid answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

Answer (score 8):

I can actually explain the difference between `LSR` and `ASR`:

- `LSR` is a logical shift right. It will shift, and the top bits become 0. This is equivalent to divide an unsigned int by a power of 2.
- `ASR` is arithmetical shift right. It will shift the number, taking into account if the number of positive or negative. It will actually shift, but top bits get the value of bit 31 (Instead of 0). This has the effect of dividing a signed integer by a power of 2.